# jsf (richfaces) readonly input text validation

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

Is there any way I can validate a jsf input text that is readonly but the value is changed upon some other events triggered?

Comment: Woudn't it be easier to validate it in the jsf page backing bean?

Comment: And how do I trigger the validation and issue the validation message?

Comment: I have added an answer as reply to the comment. Cheers

Comment: Are you changing the value by JavaScript? What exactly is the functional requirement?

Comment: @BalusC the first component, the inputText, is displaying some value that is modified by a second component, which is more complex. I did not want to make the validation on the second component, because it would have been more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem with a workaround. I have added an `inputHidden` field that has the `required` attribute `true` that will not appear on the interface, but will be validated:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.value}" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Data must be entered" />
```

The value of bean.value is changed by other event, and at some reRender on the inputHidden, the validation takes place.

Answer (score 14):

Set the `readonly` attribute to `true` only during render response phase. This way it won't be seen as readonly in all other phases than the render response phase.

```html
<h:inputText ... readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}" />
```

Comment: In my case `#{facesContext.renderResponse} returns false when drawing the HTML (had it printed in the middle of it). Anyway, it works as `#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}`. Mojarra 2.1.9.

Answer (score 2):

Answering from comment: "Woudn't it be easier to validate it in the jsf page backing bean?"
You can do application-level validation on a button click or some similar event. You can do something like this in your backing bean and link it to the event.

```
public String login(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if(**<<some validation for value in field 'firstName' in form 'userForm'>>**){
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            message.setSummary("Some Valication check");
            message.setSummary("Some Valication check!!");
            context.addMessage("userForm:firstName", message);//adds validation message for field firstName in form userForm
            return "ERROR";
        }
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: JSF won't update the model value for a `readonly="true"` input. Plus, doing valdation inside an action method instead of inside a normal validator is a poor practice.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for the info :) I did not know that setting readonly="true" for input would not update the model value. As for doing validation inside an action, I know it is not the best of practices but I think we may not be able to add the normal validator for readonly input.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to manually call the validation logic directly from your event.  Here is a model of the JSF lifecycle from IBM.

[image]

You will notice that Process Validations phase occurs before the Invoke Application phase where events are typically handled.  This occurs well after so validation will not occur automatically.